# UIScrollView performance problem

Tags: ios, performance, uiscrollview

I'm having performance issues related to touches being delivered with latency, thus making it unresponsive. The app contains lots of `UIScrollView`s, but only a couple are on the display list at once. Adding more scroll views makes latency worse, removing them makes it better.

Problems goes away if I convert the scroll views to plain old `UIView`.  Setting `scrollEnabled=NO` doesn't help, which is I guessed it should.

I traced with Instruments time profiler (image below) and UIScrollView is the culprit. Also it seems NSNotificationCenter is involved.

Again: **the scroll views aren't even on the display tree!** I might have hundreds of UIScrollViews in an array in memory, but those guys **still** affects performance.

Any ideas what to do about this?

[image: Scrollviews getting all the action]

Answer (score 1):

Set `delaysContentTouches` to NO on your scrollviews and see if the problem improves or disappears.

Comment: No, sorry it didn't make any difference.